# How can I validate number column

Tags: validation, calculated-column-formula

I have number column in my new form. 
If user write here number, I need to validate if it is multiple of value 0,5. 
For example 1 or 2,5.

I've tried formula for column validation: 
= ?*0,5
but it gives me syntax error.

Please, help. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need,

=mod([FieldName];0,5)=0

Comment: Just want to note for anyone who sees this in the future, that this formula depends on the regional settings. For languages that use a comma for a decimal point, this is correct. For languages, such as English (US), that use a period, Gintas K's answer below should work.

Comment: How can I connect it together with other folmula?  Second formula is: =IF(OR(Do<Od);FALSE;IF(OR([Nástup do zamestnania po dovolenke]<=Do);FALSE;TRUE))

Comment: Two points here: (1) If the formula you posted above is in list item validation, you don't really have to combine the two formulas, as both of them will be validated if you add '=mod([FieldName];0,5)=0' in the field validation for your field. (2) A rough guess for the combined formula would be '=IF(mod([FieldName];0,5)=0;IF(OR(Do<Od);FALSE;IF(OR([Nástup do zamestnania po dovolenke]<=Do);FALSE;TRUE));FALSE)' **beware of typos** :)

Comment: Wow, thank you for your fast response. I use second option, and it works great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following:

```
= MOD([YourColumnName],0.5) = 0
```